# highlight paragraph in docx file using python-docx

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-docx

I am trying to highlight a paragraph in a .docx file using python-docx.

```
from docx import Document
from docx.enum.text import WD_COLOR_INDEX

source_folder = 'D:/project/data2/'
f = source_folder+'test.docx'
document = Document(f)


for para in document.paragraphs:
    font1 = para.add_run().font
    font1.highlight_color = WD_COLOR_INDEX.RED
document.save(source_folder+'new.docx')
```

This code should highlight all the paragraphs in the document but it is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from docx import Document
from docx.enum.text import WD_COLOR_INDEX

source_folder = 'D:/project/data2/'
f = source_folder+'test.docx'
document = Document(f)


for para in document.paragraphs:
    for run in para.runs:
        run.font.highlight_color = WD_COLOR_INDEX.RED
document.save(source_folder+'new.docx')
```